# How to connect OV7670 to Arduino Leonardo?

Tags: arduino

I am new in Arduino domain. I have an Arduino Leonardo and a Camera OV7670 ( http://www.dx.com/p/ov7670-300kp-vga-camera-module-for-arduino-147742#.U17QZPl_tBl ). 
What I need to connect this camera to my Arduino? Shield or something like that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the module and a method to get an 8mhz clock signal from 5v to 3.3v I wrote about how to use the ov7670 on an arduino you can read about it here http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=159557.0